# Using inno to install MS DHTML components on Windows Vista and later

Tags: vb6, inno-setup

2 files required for the MS DHTML control to work properly were removed from windows vista (and win7, 8 presumably) for security reasons.

These are the DHTMLED.ocx and TRIEdit.dll.

Microsoft now supply a downloadable msi file, dhtmled.msi, which will install and register the 2 components into the following directory:

> %windir%\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\dhtmled\

I would like to build this into an inno script.

Should I run the installer on my machine first to get hold of the ocx and dll files and have separate lines for each in the inno script or should I incorporate the msi file into the script?

Also what flags should I use to prevent installation on win xp or earlier and when the files are already present?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See [Replacing the DHTML Editing Control in Windows Vista and Beyond](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa663363.aspx)

> For new applications, you can ship the installer as part of your product (with appropriate licensing) and chain to it from your own installer. The installer can be run silently and without adding an item to the installed-programs list in Windows. (For details, see the documentation for MsiExec.exe.)
>
> However, we recommend that the installer allow the DHTML Editing Control to be added to the installed-programs list. In addition, when your application is uninstalled, do not uninstall the control; instead, allow customers to uninstall it separately if they want.
>
> Note that this method of installation does not provide logo-compliant installation.

The method that is compliant would be to list this as a prerequisite that the user manually installs before running your installer.

I haven't seen anything the permits redistribution of the naked libraries under any circumstances.

Comment: 'I haven't seen anything the permits redistribution of the naked libraries under any circumstances.' Isn't this just because they know it's simpler for the end user and the files will get put in the desired location and registered correctly? Or could there be more to it than that?

Comment: Obviously, I don't want to contravene the licensing. But I would probably prefer their first legal option (the silent one) to the second. The code at this link seems like it might be what I need : http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?msi

Comment: It's about some serious potential security issues that mean users must be aware when it gets installed and have the ability to manually uninstall it separately at any time through Add/Remove Programs.